# is buddhism outside the idealism and materialism?

Tags: theravada, anatman, spiritual-materialism

is buddhism is not certainly the idealism or materialisn?Buddhism philosophy is about the consequence mechanism about five elements* and those elements aren't viewed as the material,antimatter or spirit.But the motion and change of them is showing that Buddha or at least the nearest original of his book want to say that the motion and objective reality(material or time) is real,and it sounds like materialism.But the motion is come from,where?isn't it an conscious,thinking of mind construct from data,to create the motion,the time concept and feeling about it?Some time buddhism mention about mind,but doesn't it say the mind is a part of motion of elements?
* fundamental elements (vietnamese: ngũ uẩn)

Comment: *"...But the motion and change of them is showing that Buddha or at least the nearest original of his book want to say that the motion and objective reality(material or time) is real..."* - please provide a reference to this statement and preferably to where *question-body* is copy-pasted from.

Comment: there's no copied pasted from any where,i had referred a Vietnamese word dumb

Comment: Could you add a reference to the book or text?

Comment: no that's my thinking stream,you have to research much to understand what i said.

Answer (score 1):

Buddhism points out that both are concepts, reality is free of concepts (unless we impose them).

In my experience concepts like idealism etc. are deeply ingrained, unlike "my nose is itchy", so it's useful to remember they're just in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Material(rupa) is ultimate reality in Buddhism. 
The mind(citta) is an ultimate reality too. Cittas come one by one very fast and each lasts for an extremely short period of time. The more we are mindful, the more we can see these cittas. If we aren't mindful, like most people(unfortunately), we can't see the individual cittas that make up our stream of consciousness or our mind stream very well because they blur together.

It's not that "Conceptual Reality" is wrong, The entire Tipitaka  is conceptual. Among the many purposes of the Buddha's teaching, is making us understand  the difference  between "Ultimate  Reality" and "Conceptual  Reality" because we usually just blur the two realities together.

Comment: I hope I understood the question. Anyway, spiritual materialism is about how one treats the spiritual world the same way they treat the material world?

Answer (score 0):

Yes without going to the extremes existence and non-existence or eternalism and nihilism Buddha taught the middle path which is Dependent Origination.